# Insert array as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

My form is submitting attributes into a table, one attribute (:permission) is an array of strings. I got the error that it cannot insert an array to type string so I tried adding to_s and the error is gone but now it rollsback. I am not sure how to see the error or how to fix this.

My Form:

```
<%= f.label :permission, "Permission Level" %>
<%= f.select :permission, [ ["Read Only", "read"], ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"], ["Master of All", "all"] ], {prompt: "Select Permission Level"}, {:multiple => true, class: "input-lg"} %>
```

My controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :permission => [].to_s)
end
```

My Log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 24.147.48.156 at 2014-04-23 13:06:05 -0700
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"spaGUvxtoK2ipPrSkmGmMuIChVcEtzrWJbt/b1oByG4=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Tester", "email"=>"t
est@x.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "permission"=>["", "ip_voice", "ip_video_telephon
y"], "admin"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@x.com') LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

I am not sure how to insert the array or how to view the error, any help appreciated.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token
has_many :questions
serialize :permission

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :permission, presence: true

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }                         


has_secure_password

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.hash(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private 

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.hash(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to `serialize` permission attribute

In your user model,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :permission
end
```

This tells Rails to convert the permission attribute which is dealt as Array object on Rails layer to be String object in database layer.

---

edit 1:

Try editing the user_params method.

```rb
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :permission => [] )
end
```

Comment: It rollsback the same log is shown. The error is permission cannot be blank